# How do I load a file resource in Java and read its content with Spring boot?

Tags: java, file, spring-boot

The following code works:

```
 private List<String> readFile() {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("passwords.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    InputStreamReader streamReader = null;
    try {
      streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
      String line;
      while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        line.trim();
        result.add(line);
      }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
  }
```

However, I've been told that I can do it in a more sophisticated way: to inject the resource with spring boot like this:

```
@Value("classpath:passwords.txt")
  private Resource passwordFile;
```

And then to use Java 7 method `Files.readAllLines(Path, Chatset)`. However, when I rewrote my code to the following:

```
@PostConstruct
  private List<String> readFile() {
    try {
      result =  Files.readAllLines(passwordFile.toFile.getPath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    }
    ....
  }
```

It seems that my `result` variable has size 0 (which is wrong). Where is my mistake? Or how do I rewrite my working code in a more sophisticated way?

Comment: maybe `passWords.txt` vs `passwords.txt` ...?

Comment: A resource is not a file and you shoud never assume that you can access it as one. Even if you manage to make it work during development it might break when deployed differently. Use `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).lines().collect(Collectors.toList())` or similar and consume the inputstream of a resource